# Excel VBA Chart Positions not constant

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where I create graphs in VBA and then place them according to named ranges in the worksheet.

```
graph3.Height = gRange.Height
graph3.Width = gRange.Width
graph3.Top = gRange.Cells(1, 1).Top
graph3.Left = gRange.Cells(1, 1).Left
```

It used to work fine but for some reason the graph no longer is positioned in the correct location. When I set a a stop point on any of the four lines and then continue to run the procedure, the graph returns to the correct position. Has anyone ever experienced this and how can I correct it?

Comment: I just realized that it was the window zoom was affecting the position of the graph. I was able to correcting it by adding the following at the beginning of the sub;     ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100

Comment: What version of Excel? I haven't noticed Window.Zoom affect position and size of objects since Excel 2003.

Comment: I am using Excel 2016 32-bit. I don't know if this changes anything but I noticed this only after updating from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Comment: Huh, I just tested it. One time I did this with the zoom at 90, and when I changed to 100, the chart was a little bit wider than the range. I then went back to 90, and the chart lined up fine, and returned to 100, and the chart now did line up fine. It only happened once: I couldn't make the chart not line up again, no matter what combinations of initial and final zoom I tried.